# Access data passed from another app through URL Scheme at launch of receiver application?

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme, openurl

Can we access data passed from another app through URL Scheme at launch of receiver application? I am passing a Locale and app language information to be set on the receiver application. But I cannot set the locale and language with the received information since

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
```

is accessed only after launch.

Is there any way in which I can do this? What I am trying to do is set the new apps language using another app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
{
       NSString *data=[[[url query] substringFromIndex:5]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
       data= [data stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```